# CSRF desde angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Como hago una petición a un web services que requiere CSRF?

tengo este servicio:

```
  app.service('Names', function($resource, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
return $resource('http://datos.24x7.cl/get_generic_ajax/', null,
  {
    'getAll': { method:'POST',
                headers : {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                transformRequest: function(data) {
                  return $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);
          }}
  });
```

})

y el controlador encargado de ejecutar la petición es este:

```
          Names.getAll({

        csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'x7g7Yk4iLf76uW9AbMge5lJtbuFDzw7x',
        entrada: 'juan carlos'

      }, function(response){


        $scope.datoAdquerido = response.data;
        console.log(response);

      }
      )
```

y el servidor responde con un error porque requiere  CSRF!

como le mando eso? saludos.

Comment: CSRF? En serio? Que yo sepa, eso funciona para exploits maliciosos.

Comment: me puedes explicar ? es que mediante el programa post activando interceptor me permite consumir el dato y me retorna la respuesta pero cuando lo hago desde el codigo me sale error :o

Comment: El CSRF token suele enviarlo el servidor por una cookie y luego en tu petición $http debes enviarlo en los headers. Si haces la petición desde un dominio diferente al del servicio web y este no tiene CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) activado no podrás recibir la respuesta debido a que no esta preparado para recibir peticiones de dominios externos.